# Strange behavior with variable

Tags: actionscript-3, action

There is very strange problem with variable in action script. I use it (variable) to dinamically change width of progress bar in my mp3 player, 
here is code:

```
filledProgress.width = Math.round (progressPercent * 1.56);
```

it works very good in the beginning, but after some time it stops, by stops I mean, filledProgress.width doesn't want to change its value from 0, although on the right part of expression is always some result, I even created different variable, to check whether it will get value from:

```
Math.round (progressPercent * 1.56);
```

And it works perfectly well, but filledProgress.width didn't change at all, however, after i reload and clear cash in my browser, it again starts to work, and again after short period of time stops.

What can it be?

Comment: Of what type is progressPercent? If it's an int or a uint you might get some unusual behaviour trying to round it. Make sure it's a Number type.

Comment: Yes, it a Number type. I tried to create another progress bar for testing, and I didn't put it inside sprite, so it works fine, without any kind of problems, so I don't know what it can be...

Comment: You need to run a 'trace' on 'progressPercent' as it changes - ie: trace("progressPercent = "+progressPercent); Also it might pay to trace out the value that gets ADDED to progressPercent. If either result is ever NaN (not a number) that may be causing the problem.

Comment: I think progressPercent is not a problem, because as I commented before, I created another movie clip and put it out side of the sprite, and its width changes without problem. If you want you can check here my full code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189942/how-to-change-width-of-movieclip-inside-sprite

Answer (score 0):

This behavior may occur due to removed event listener.

Check where you remove event listener in which you update width.

Comment: No that event Listener never removed, because inside it also changing remaining time to the end of song, and that time changing consistently, it means listener catch the event fine, only width of that progress bar doesn't change