# how to change width of movieclip inside sprite

Tags: actionscript-3

I really need your help... Below is my code for mp3 player. And the annoying problem is inside updateTime function, test.width doesn't want to change its value from 0, and that very strange behavior and I cannot understand why...

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;
    import flash.media.SoundTransform;

import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.media.SoundLoaderContext;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;



var playlist:XML = new XML();                    
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var songNamok:String = new String();
var songPathok:String = new String();

var arrayUrl:Array = new Array(); 
var arrayNames:Array = new Array();
var track:Number = 0;

var myMusic:Sound = new Sound();
var soundFile:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var sTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
var pressedButton:Object = new Object();
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 
var IsPausePressed:Number = 0;


tf.color = 0xFF0000;
txtLengthOfSong.setStyle("textFormat", tf);

var tfforSong:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 

tfforSong.font = "Arial"; 
tfforSong.size = 16; 
tfforSong.bold = true;
tfforSong.color = 0xFFffff;




movingString.setStyle("textFormat", tfforSong);










//Create test bar (progressBar) in this place, all childs are drawn objects, 
//they have width and height

var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(container);
container.addChild(emptyProgress);
container.addChild(loadedProgress);
container.addChild(test);
container.addChild(transparentProgress);




container.setChildIndex(emptyProgress,0);
container.setChildIndex(loadedProgress,1);
container.setChildIndex(test, 2);
container.setChildIndex(transparentProgress,3);





var secondContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(secondContainer);
secondContainer.addChild(emptyVolume);
secondContainer.addChild(filledVolume);
secondContainer.addChild(transparentVolume);





//In accordance to this timer test (progress bar) and
// remaining time will be changed
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(50);

var myTimerForTremble = new Timer(5);
var songPosition:Number = 0;
var myContext:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(5000);




var firstTime = 0;


buttonPlay.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, playMusic);
buttonStop.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, stopMusic);
buttonPause.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, pauseMusic);
buttonPlay.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, startTimer);
buttonStop.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, startTimer);
buttonPause.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, startTimer);
transparentProgress.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changePosition);
transparentVolume.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeVolume);



myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateTime);


myTimerForTremble.addEventListener (TimerEvent.TIMER, tremble);
buttonPlay.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, stopTimer);
buttonStop.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, stopTimer);
buttonPause.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, stopTimer);








filledVolume.width = (channel.soundTransform.volume * 10)*0.98;





function progressOfDownloading (event:ProgressEvent):void{

     var loadedMp3:Number = Math.round(100 * (event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal)); 

    loadedProgress.width = 35;




}


function songIsOver (evt:Event):void{

    evt.currentTarget.removeEventListener(evt.type, songIsOver);



    myTimer.stop();


firstTime = 0;


songPosition = 0;


try {                                             
         channel.stop();
         myMusic.close();

    } catch(e:Error){
        channel.stop();      

    }



ExternalInterface.call("PlayNextSong","");


}


function playTheMusic ():void{

    myTimer.stop();


firstTime = 0;


if (IsPausePressed == 0)
songPosition = 0;


try {                                            
         channel.stop();
         myMusic.close();


    } catch(e:Error){
        channel.stop();  

    }




playMusic();




}


function changeVolume(evt:MouseEvent):void{
    var x:Number = new Number();

    x = evt.stageX;

    var percentOfVolume:Number = new Number();


    percentOfVolume = Math.floor((x-40)/0.98);

    percentOfVolume = percentOfVolume / 10;

    sTransform.volume = percentOfVolume;



    channel.soundTransform = sTransform;



    filledVolume.width = x - 40;


}


function changePosition (evt:MouseEvent):void{

    if (firstTime == 1)
    {

    var x:Number = new Number();
    x = evt.stageX;
    var percent:Number = new Number();

 var totalSeconds:Number = myMusic.length;
 percent =  myMusic.length/100 * ((x-22)/1.56);
    songPosition = percent;

    channel.stop();

    channel =  myMusic.play(songPosition);

    channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, songIsOver);

    }
}

//This function will launch every 50 milliseconds, because of myTimer


function updateTime(evt:TimerEvent):void{



        var progressok:String = new String(channel.position / myMusic.length);

        var progressPercent:Number = new Number (channel.position / myMusic.length);




       progressPercent =  progressPercent * 100;

    //this is the main problem: test.width doesn't want to change at all, however
    // if I will write solid value like: 10, 12, 13 it works, and also when I write
    // test.width = Math.random() * 100; it also works...
       test.width =  Math.round(progressPercent * 1.56);












    var currentPosition:Number = new Number();
    currentPosition = channel.position;

    var timeRemain:Number = new Number();
    timeRemain = myMusic.length - channel.position;

    var totalSeconds:Number = timeRemain/1000;

    var minutes:Number = Math.floor(totalSeconds/60);
    var seconds = Math.floor(totalSeconds)%60;
    if (seconds<10) {
    seconds = "0"+seconds;
    }


 txtLengthOfSong.text = minutes+":"+seconds;

    var randomHeight:Number = new Number();

    randomHeight = Math.random()*100;



    if (randomHeight > 55)
    randomHeight = 55;
    if (randomHeight < 0)
    randomHeight = 0;

    column1.height = randomHeight;
    column2.height = randomHeight - (Math.random()*100);
    column3.height = randomHeight / 3 * 2;
    column4.height = randomHeight - (Math.random()*100);
    column5.height = randomHeight - (Math.random()*100);
    column6.height = randomHeight - (Math.random()*100);
    column7.height = randomHeight - (Math.random()*100);
    column8.height = randomHeight - (Math.random()*100);
    column9.height = randomHeight - (Math.random()*100);
    column10.height = randomHeight - (Math.random()*100);



if (movingString.textWidth > 150)
{
    var deletedChar:String = new String();
    var movingText:String = new String();


    movingText = movingString.text;

    deletedChar = movingText.charAt(0);

    movingText = movingText.substr(1) + deletedChar;

    movingString.text = movingText;




}




}







function stopTimer(evt:MouseEvent):void{

    pressedButton.y = 145;
    myTimerForTremble.stop();

}

function tremble(evt:TimerEvent):void{



        pressedButton.y = 145 + ((Math.random()*10) - 5);







}

function startTimer (evt:MouseEvent):void{

    if (!myTimerForTremble.running)

    pressedButton = evt.target;

    myTimerForTremble.start();
}


function pauseMusic(evt:MouseEvent = null):void{
IsPausePressed = 1;
    songPosition = channel.position;

    pressedButton.y = 145;
    myTimerForTremble.stop();
    channel.stop();
    firstTime = 0;
   myTimer.stop();


}

ExternalInterface.addCallback('pauseTheMusic', pauseMusic);
ExternalInterface.addCallback('resetSongPosition', resetSongPosition);

function resetSongPosition ():void{

    songPosition = 0;


}


ExternalInterface.addCallback('select_track', SelectTrack);
function SelectTrack(songPath:String, songName:String):void{

    songPathok = songPath;
    songNamok = songName;

     playTheMusic();

}




function playMusic (evt:MouseEvent = null):void{
    if (firstTime == 0)
    firstTime = 1;
    else
    return;

    soundFile.url = songPathok;

    movingString.text = songNamok + "       ";



     var nextTitle:Sound = new Sound(soundFile);
    myMusic = nextTitle;



    channel =  myMusic.play(songPosition);

    channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, songIsOver);

    pressedButton.y = 145;
    myTimerForTremble.stop();




    myTimer.start();


    var percentOfVolume:Number = new Number();


    percentOfVolume = Math.floor(filledVolume.width/0.98);

    percentOfVolume = percentOfVolume / 10;

    sTransform.volume = percentOfVolume;



    channel.soundTransform = sTransform;








}

function stopMusic (evt:MouseEvent):void{
    firstTime = 0;


    pressedButton.y = 145;
    myTimerForTremble.stop();
    channel.stop();
    songPosition = 0;
myTimer.stop();


}
```

Comment: ?  You set the `.width` property of the movieClip in question. I think though that maybe there's more to your question than you let on?

Comment: Thanks for reply! So, if I want to change width of filledProgress, all I need to do: filledProgress.width = 100; is it correct?

Comment: that's right - you should really try it before creating a question on stackoverflow

Comment: No, it not a question, I know that I can set width in that way, but problem is a little bit deeper. I'm developing mp3 player, and I created progress bar, it updates its width according to timer function, and the problem I cannot change width of that progress bar via variable, if you want you can check my previous question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117620/strange-behavior-with-variable

Comment: where is this movieclip you are referring to? where do you create it, is it empty? please update your code to get a reasonable answer.